# Setting Max Buffer Size for MariaDB in PHP not working

Tags: php, mariadb

**So the problem was MariaDB mediumblob only accepts 1mb size file and I was trying to set it to higher value in PHP, I tried doing these**

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=e-commercedb", "root", "", array
        (PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE=>1024*1024*10));
```

**I also tried doing these but still not working**

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 1024*1024* 10);
```

Im using PHP version 7.4.29
MariaDB version -> 10.4.24-MariaDB

I was expecting to insert larger file in my mediumblob column after doing that, anyone knows whats the problem and solution here?

Comment: I edited to clarify that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL 5.5 in 2010, but both products have changed enough since then that you should not think of them as compatible or one as a variant of the other.

Comment: Ohh sorry I thought its mysql because of XAMPP then PHPadmin

Comment: Share your insert query and other php codes if possible

Comment: Im not inserting yet and still trying to modify the buffer size, this is the error it throws btw 
Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE'